# Properly handle VK_DELETE when subclassing edit control

Tags: c++, winapi, subclassing, editcontrol

I am subclassing edit control to accept only decimal numbers.

Everything works fine, and the only thing left for me is processing the case when user selects portion of the text and presses `Delete` key ( `VK_DELETE` ).

My question is following:

Does pressing a `Delete` key ( `VK_DELETE` ) sends some message like `WM_CLEAR` that I can use for my processing, or do I have to handle `WM_KEYDOWN` in my subclassing procedure and do the processing there?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running Spy++ on Notepad's edit control, I have arrived at the conclusion that `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_KEYUP` is all you get.

```
<000001> 0015082E S WM_KILLFOCUS hwndGetFocus:0015082E
<000002> 0015082E R WM_KILLFOCUS
<000003> 0015082E S WM_SETFOCUS hwndLoseFocus:002D0830
<000004> 0015082E R WM_SETFOCUS
<000005> 0015082E P message:0x0118 [Unknown] wParam:0000FFFF lParam:FFFFF960001DA744
<000006> 0015082E P message:0x0118 [Unknown] wParam:0000FFFF lParam:FFFFF960001DA744
<000007> 0015082E P message:0x0118 [Unknown] wParam:0000FFFF lParam:FFFFF960001DA744
<000008> 0015082E P message:0x0118 [Unknown] wParam:0000FFFF lParam:FFFFF960001DA744
<000009> 0015082E P message:0x0118 [Unknown] wParam:0000FFFF lParam:FFFFF960001DA744
<000010> 0015082E P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_DELETE cRepeat:1 ScanCode:53 fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<000011> 0015082E P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_DELETE cRepeat:1 ScanCode:53 fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
<000012> 0015082E P message:0x0118 [Unknown] wParam:0000FFFF lParam:FFFFF960001DA744
<000013> 0015082E P message:0x0118 [Unknown] wParam:0000FFFF lParam:FFFFF960001DA744
<000014> 0015082E P message:0x0118 [Unknown] wParam:0000FFFF lParam:FFFFF960001DA744
<000015> 0015082E P message:0x0118 [Unknown] wParam:0000FFFF lParam:FFFFF960001DA744
<000016> 0015082E P message:0x0118 [Unknown] wParam:0000FFFF lParam:FFFFF960001DA744
<000017> 0015082E S EM_GETSEL lpdwStart:0020F330 lpdwEnd:0020F334
<000018> 0015082E R EM_GETSEL wStart:2 wEnd:2 lpdwStart:0020F330 (2) lpdwEnd:0020F334 (2)
<000019> 0015082E S WM_KILLFOCUS hwndGetFocus:(null)
<000020> 0015082E R WM_KILLFOCUS
```

The relevant lines are `<000010>` and `<000011>`: the `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` are back-to-back. There's no `WM_CLEAR` called at all. There *is* an interesting 0x0118 message, but that shows up on every keypress, not just the delete key.

Comment: Thank you for validating my assumptions. I guess `WM_KEYDOWN` is the only way to go. Best regards.